# How to track the start and end time of a raid5 rebuild?

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm, software-raid, raid5

This is my first post on the forum, so bear with me.

I am new to the linux environment and also new to raid configurations. 
I am doing a work project where for part of this project I am measuring RAID5 rebuild time.

I currently have 4 active drives in the RAID5 configuration. 
I am going to fail one of them.

When I fail one of the drives, will it automatically start rebuilding?
Additionally, I want to track the time it takes to rebuild.

I know /proc/mdstat will tell me its progress, but i want to be able to walk away while its rebuilding, and to come back with some log that tells me how long it took to rebuild.

Thanks in advance to whomever reads this.

Answer (score 0):

> When I fail one of the drives, will it automatically start rebuilding?

Unless you have a spare already part of the array, it will only start rebuilding when you manually add another drive to the array. Can't very well grab a random drive without permission.

Note that while a drive has not yet been kicked from an array, using `mdadm --replace` might be a better way to start rebuilding; it allows the to-be-replaced drive to assist the rebuild process.

> to come back with some log that tells me how long it took to rebuild

There are log messages with timestamps you can use to get the exact time.

```
[117687.034515] md: recovery of RAID array md100
...
[117709.482483] md: md100: recovery done.
```

Then there is `mdadm --wait /dev/md100` to wait for a running operation to finish. If you combine that with `time` you can measure how long it took from the `mdadm` utility perspective, but the timestamps as printed by the kernel itself should be more accurate. If that kind of accuracy even matters in your case...

For more detailed statistics (which segment took so long?) you'll have to monitor the drives and log their throughput throughout the process on your own, `mdadm` doesn't really help you with that. You can watch current progress either through `/proc/mdstat` or via the sysfs interface under `/sys/block/md100/md/[dev-sdx/recovery_start]` plenty of interesting things there so you don't always have to parse the human-readable mdstat.